How can I rewrite my function to ensure that the "found = true" statement is reached?
In my main function, the user inputs an ID number as a string variable which is then passed to the function above. I have tested multiple ID numbers that are in the txt file, and all of them return fail. So, I am assuming this is an issue of the function never reaching the "found = true" statement, but I cannot figure out why. The txt file just has ID numbers and names in the following format:
123
John Smith
etc.

string lookupEmployee(string idNum)
{
    ifstream file;
    string line, employeeName, fail = "Employee not found. ";
    bool found = false;

    file.open("Employees.txt");

    if (file.fail())
    {
        cout << "File failed to open. " << endl;
        exit(1);
        return "-1";
    }

    while (!file.eof())
    {
        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            if (line == idNum)
            {
                getline(file, employeeName);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    file.close();

    if (!found)
    {
        return fail;
    }
    else
    {
        return employeeName;
    }
}


OT: The exit function will never return. It just exits your program right then and there.

simplify, and it also will help in fixing bugs. Use if(file) to test it opened successfully. Use for(std::string line; std::getline(file, line);) ... to process file line by line. No need to explicitly call close, unless it's needed, the file will be closed when going out of scope.

the while loop, while(!file.eof()){} is not needed.  The while loop while(getline(file, line)){} will exit when reaching the end of the file.  Using two while loops may result in skipping over idNum.

You're missing a description of what this code is supposed to do and why you believe it should work.

The problem is that while (!file.eof()) loop...
The break statement only exits the current loop, not all loops that are nested inside each other.
Which means that the inner while (getline(file, line)) loop will end, but the outer while (!file.eof()) will continue and you will read until the end of the file.
This would have been very easy to see if you used a debugger to step through the code line by line.
So the solution is to simply remove the outer loop and only keep the inner loop.

The above is only one problem, there's still another: You need to always read two lines!
If line != idNum then you will not read the name on the next line, which means the next time the loop iterates it will read the name as the "id".
You also don't need the break statement, you could return directly from inside the loop.
So the proper loop could be something like this:
for (std::string id, name; std::getline(file, id) && std::getline(file, name); /* Empty */)
{
    if (id == idNum)
    {
        // We found the correct record, return the name immediately
        return name;
    }
}

// If the loop ends, we didn't find anything
// ...


Lastly a recommendation to improve the code in general and make it more effective: Read everything at once, store as a structure Employee which contain the id as an unsigned integer and the name.
Store the structure in a std::unordered_map<unsigned, Employee>. which maps the employee id to the structure containing the data about the employee.
And when you need to find the name of someone with a specific id, you could do something like
if (auto const iter = employees.find(id); iter != employees.end()))
{
    // Found the employee
    return iter->second.name;
}

[Use your own names for the map and other variables]
